# Activity Result APIs (TakePicture() camera): Failure delivering result ResultInfo (App Crash)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android-image-capture, activity-result-api

I have been struggling with the issue of having my activity being **destroyed sometimes** while taking a picture with the camera app., resulting in the below error and an app crash.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity 
{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.MyActivity}
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I have followed the Google documentation on how to take a picture with the camera [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). It still produced the above error after 3 or 4 trials.

I abandoned the old `startActivityForResult` method for the new `Activity Result APIs`, yet still the same problem exists.

The documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#register), specifically states the following:

> When starting an activity for a result, it is possible (and, in cases
> of memory-intensive operations such as camera usage, almost certain)
> that your process and your activity will be destroyed due to low
> memory.
>
> For this reason, the Activity Result APIs decouple the result callback
> from the place in your code where you launch the other activity. As
> the result callback needs to be available when your process and
> activity are recreated, the callback must be unconditionally
> registered every time your activity is created, even if the logic of
> launching the other activity only happens based on user input or other
> business logic.

Thus, it states that even if the activity is destroyed, the new Activity Result APIs handle this issue somehow.

Here's the code I am using now:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private Uri photoURI;
private ImageView firstImage;
ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> intentActivityResultLauncher;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);
        firstImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView_camera_open_one);
        intentActivityResultLauncher=registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
                result -> {
         if (firstImage != null && photoURI != null)
                    firstImage.setImageURI(photoURI);
                });
}

private void openCamera(int viewId) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error).show();
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        intentActivityResultLauncher.launch(photoURI);
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` or fixing the activity to portrait, doesn't help.

Is there a proper fix for this?

**Full stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.Activity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.Activity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4626)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4659)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.activities.Activity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5324)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4659) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.myapp.activities.Activity.onActivityResult(MyActivity.java:269)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4613) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4659) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: You need to include full stacktrace not just a  part of it.

Comment: `firstImage.setImageURI(photoURI);` Check photoURI for null before use. And dont use if null.

Comment: You are not using  Intent takePictureIntent;.

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal I edited the question and included full stacktrace.

Comment: Okay, perhaps while sanitizing the logs/code you're excluding out a lot of details. Your log says `EventReportActivity` has a `onActivityResult` method which is using an `arrayList` object and trying to get a value from the `arrayList`.

Comment: @blackapps I added checks for nulls for both the photoURI and the ImageView. Still issue is persisting. I am not using takePictureIntent yes, I only pass the uri to the file I created, since the takePicture contract expects only a URI.